# JavaFX - Синхронизация работы slider и spinner при изменении значения

Tags: javafx

Как синхронизировать работу `slider` и `spinner`? При изменении значении одного, меняется и значение второго. Как заставить их работать вместе?

Код:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private FlowPane pane;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;
    private Label label;
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(1);
        slider.setMax(9);
        slider.setValue(3);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(1);

        Spinner <Integer>  spinner = new Spinner <Integer> ();
        final int initialValue= 3;
        SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1,9,initialValue );
        spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);


        this.stage = stage;
        pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(spinner, slider);
        scene = new Scene(pane , 350 , 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Забавно, но при использовании промежуточного `SimpleStringProperty` сработал только один единственный вариант:

```
    // Связываем ObjectProperty<Integer> и DoubleProperty через промежуточное свойство:
    SimpleStringProperty sp = new SimpleStringProperty();
    sp.bindBidirectional(valueFactory.valueProperty(), new IntegerStringConverter());
    sp.bindBidirectional(slider.valueProperty(), new DecimalFormat("0"));
```

Итоговый вариант:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SliderSpinnerMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(1);
        slider.setMax(9);
        slider.setValue(3);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(1);
        // еще немного приукрасим:
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(1);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(0);

        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<Integer>();
        final int initialValue = 3;
        SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory =
                new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 9, initialValue);
        spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);

        // Связываем ObjectProperty<Integer> и DoubleProperty через промежуточное свойство:
        SimpleStringProperty sp = new SimpleStringProperty();
        sp.bindBidirectional(valueFactory.valueProperty(), new IntegerStringConverter());
        sp.bindBidirectional(slider.valueProperty(), new DecimalFormat("0"));

        VBox root = new VBox(spinner, slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 430, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

С другой стороны, можно и без промежуточного `SimpleStringProperty` обойтись — просто обработчики написать:

```
    // Связываем ObjectProperty<Integer> и DoubleProperty:
    slider.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
                valueFactory.setValue((int) Math.round(newValue.doubleValue()));
            });
    spinner.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Integer> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) -> {
                if (newValue != (int) Math.round(slider.getValue()))
                    slider.setValue(newValue);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

С `Spinner<Integer> spinner` большие проблемы с приведением типов, поэтому можно попробовать так:

```
Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<>();
final double initialValue = 3D;
SpinnerValueFactory<Double> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory( 1D, 9D, initialValue, 1D );
spinner.setValueFactory( valueFactory );

valueFactory.valueProperty().bindBidirectional( slider.valueProperty().asObject() );

valueFactory.setConverter( new StringConverter<Double>() {
    private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    @Override
    public String toString( Double value ) {
        if ( value == null )
            return "";
        return df.format( value );
    }
    @Override
    public Double fromString( String value ) {
        try {
            if ( value == null )
                return null;
            value = value.trim();
            if ( value.length() < 1 )
                return null;
            return df.parse(value).doubleValue();
        } catch ( ParseException ex ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( ex );
        } 
    }
});
```